# Bind ember generated elementId, Ember+Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am trying to implement [Bootstrap Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)(The **simple Collapsible** at the end of the section) using `Ember.View`
I can't find a way to bind the view id, 

**collapse.handlebars**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" {{bindAttr data-target="view.contentId"}}>
  simple collapsible
</button>

{{view view.collapseContentView class="collapse in"}}
```

**My View:**

```
App.CollapseView = Ember.View.extend({

  templateName: 'collapse',

  collapseContentView: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Collapse body text")
  }),

  contentId: function(){
    return "#"+this.get('collapseContentView.elementId')
  }.property()

})
```

I do not want to set id manually instead I want to use the ember generated one, Any reason why this doesn't work ?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could put together a JSFiddle. Looking at the code, I think you need to make the `contentId` property dependent on the `collapseContentView.elementId`.

Comment: I'll put up a fiddle soon, & I think the dependency is causing a "Maximum Call Stack Size exceeded" Error that's why I removed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collapseContentView` is a view class (`extend`) and will not have an `elementId` until you instantiate it (`create`).

In your template, when you do `{{view view.collapseContentView}}` that will create a new instance of the view, but it will not change the value of `view.collapseContentView`, it will still be a class, and thus `view.collapseContentView.elementId` will not make sense.

I would recommend using [Ember.ContainerView](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/container_view.js), which is a great way to programmatically control views. Here is an example of using a container view to handle events  between two views http://www.emberplay.com#/workspace/1140286638.

Comment: exactly the problem was with extending & when I tried Ember.View.create() I could'nt use {{view view.myView}} I need to do a append() in this case I guess, containerView is what I've been looking for Thanks :)